# Include surrounding lines of text file match in output using Python 2.7.3

Tags: python, regex, text-files, output

I've been working on a program which assists in log analysis. It finds error or fail messages using regex and prints them to a new .txt file. However, it would be much more beneficial if the program including the top and bottom 4 lines around what the match is. I can't figure out how to do this! Here is a part of the existing program:

```
def error_finder(filepath):
source = open(filepath, "r").readlines()
error_logs = set()
my_data = []
for line in source:
    line = line.strip()
    if re.search(exp, line):
        error_logs.add(line)
```

I'm assuming something needs to be added to the very last line, but I've been working on this for a bit and either am not applying myself fully or just can't figure it out.

Any advice or help on this is appreciated.

Thank you!

Comment: Why is `error_logs` a set instead of a list?

Comment: agree with @miorel - make it a list, and you can access the last n and next n lines easily

Comment: Unless the logs are pretty small (which is unlikely if he needs a tool like this), he probably wants to buffer this instead of dumping it in to a giant in-memory list.

Comment: I used set to make sure all entries are unique. I don't want duplicates in the output. The log files I use can end up being very large with multiple lines saying the same thing.

Comment: If you want to capture the surrounding messages, you should de-dupe after parsing.  Also, you should consider if you want to make the parsed log unique on just the triggering message, or on the block of surrounding messages as well.

Comment: If the regex matches on line 8 and again on line 11, do you want your output to contain [4-5-6-7-8-9-10-11-12] and [7-8-9-10-11-12-13-14-15], or a more useful [4-5-6-7-8-9-10-11-12-13-14-15]?

Answer (score 0):

Why python?

```
grep -C4 '^your_regex$' logfile > outfile.txt
```

Answer (score 0):

Some comments:

- I'm not sure why `error_logs` is a set instead of a list.
- Using `readlines()` will read the entire file in memory, which will be inefficient for large files. You should be able to just iterate over the file a line at a time.
- `exp` (which you're using for `re.search`) isn't defined anywhere, but I assume that's elsewhere in your code.

Anyway, here's complete code that should do what you want without reading the whole file in memory. It will also preserve the order of input lines.

```
import re
from collections import deque

exp = '\d'
# matches numbers, change to what you need

def error_finder(filepath, context_lines = 4):
  source = open(filepath, 'r')
  error_logs = []

  buffer = deque(maxlen=context_lines)
  lines_after = 0

  for line in source:
    line = line.strip()
    if re.search(exp, line):
      # add previous lines first
      for prev_line in buffer:
        error_logs.append(prev_line)
      # clear the buffer
      buffer.clear()
      # add current line
      error_logs.append(line)
      # schedule lines that follow to be added too
      lines_after = context_lines
    elif lines_after > 0:
      # a line that matched the regex came not so long ago
      lines_after -= 1
      error_logs.append(line)
    else:
      buffer.append(line)

  # maybe do something with error_logs? I'll just return it
  return error_logs
```

Answer (score 0):

I suggest to use index loop instead of for each loop, try this:

```
error_logs = list()
for i in range(len(source)):
    line = source[i].strip()
    if re.search(exp, line):
        error_logs.append((line,i-4,i+4))
```

in this case your errors log will contain ('line of error', line index - 4, line index + 4), so you can get these lines later form "source"